# List of all repositories with a project

Tags: git, command, repository, bitbucket

In GIT, I am trying to get the list of all the repositories within a git project using the below command

```
curl GET -k https://host-name/bit-bucket/projects/project-name?role=member
```

However, with this command i am getting a lot of information which i don't need. Is there a way i filter out just the list of all the repositories within the project?

Example:

```
<span class="repository-name"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-devtools-repository">Repository</span><a href="/bitbucket/projects/TEST/repos/17018_test2/browse" data-repository-id="344">17012_test3</a></span><div class="public-lozenge aui-lozenge aui-lozenge-subtle">Public</div></td></tr><tr><td><span class="repository-name"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-devtools-repository">Repository</span><a href="/bitbucket/projects/TEST/repos/17084_test4/browse" data-repository-id="341">17014_test1</a></span><div class="public-lozenge aui-lozenge aui-lozenge-subtle">Public</div></td></tr>
```

Also, is this the command or i am missing something?

Comment: Any help here please?

Comment: As of now i am reading the html content of the web page and using split() method, i am fetching the name of the repositories.